# MiddleName Field cannot find in in ".fields.getMap()"

Tags: apex, account, sobject, fields, describesobject

We've just enabled the Middle Name and Suffix Fields feature and encountered the below issue.

**SUMMERY** : Just after enabling "Middle Name and Suffix Fields", Implementation of custom apex logic in a static method vs running similar code snippet separately in an anonymous apex gives different result;

- Runing as a method : null pointer exception (no middleName field)
- Runing as anonymous : works fine!

**DESCRIPTION** : Below code throws an error while trying to access the middle name field in a static method,

```
private static Map<String,String> compHistoryObjDevNameToFieldName; 
// this will hold field name to label in order to access as a cache
/**
 * Returns:   field label of the object
 * field label  name will  return  from  compHistoryObjDevNameToFieldName if the value 
 * is cached in compHistoryObjDevNameToFieldName map it will return the value directly
 * or if  the  value  does  not exsist the logic will  cache the  new value and return
 **/ 
public static String getFieldLabel(Id objectId, String fieldName) {
    // prepare the key of the map ObjectId prefix+fieldname 
    String recordPrefix = objectId.getSobjectType().getDescribe().getKeyPrefix(); 
    String ObjDevNameKey = recordPrefix + fieldName;

    //1. initialse map
    //if the map is null initialize the instance
    if (compHistoryObjDevNameToFieldName == null) {
        compHistoryObjDevNameToFieldName = new Map<String,String>();
    }

    //if the key is not contains add the nmew field to the map
    if (!compHistoryObjDevNameToFieldName.containsKey(ObjDevNameKey)) {
        Schema.DescribeSobjectResult objDesc = objectId.getSobjectType().getDescribe();
        compHistoryObjDevNameToFieldName.put(ObjDevNameKey, 
                                objDesc.fields.getMap().get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel());
    }

    // return the field label
    return compHistoryObjDevNameToFieldName.get(ObjDevNameKey);
}
```

However while debugging this issue, we found that if we access the fields.getMap() directly in an
anonymous execution, this gives the expected result.

Please refer the code **executed in an anonymous window**;

```
    //Id objectId = '0011900000ApDykAAF'; // Person Account
    //Id objectId = '0011900000BvwU6'; // Organisation
    Id objectId = '0031900000AvXtg'; // Contact

    //Accessing the method which contains the similar logic
    try{
        // System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object at this point
        system.debug('Result::' + LibUtil.getFieldLabel(objectId, 'MiddleName'));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        system.debug('Exception::' + e);
    }

    //implementing the similar logic(same set of code contains inside the method LibUtil.getFieldLabel()) in anonymous window
    Schema.DescribeSobjectResult objDesc = objectId.getSobjectType().getDescribe();
    Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fieldMapForLabel = objDesc.fields.getMap();
    for(String key : fieldMapForLabel.keySet()){
        system.debug('DEBUG :: '+objDesc.fields.getMap().get(key));
    }
```

**QUESTION**: why is the MiddleName  field is not available when access the field from a method with .fields.getMap().get('MiddleName').getDescribe().getLabel()

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your class is 'with sharing'?

Comment: No it isn't with sharing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found an answer for my question, what I only had to do is to change the version of the API to 35 :-|